# Connection Refused Exception when trying to connect Iphone to Windows using Xamarin

Tags: networking, tcp, xamarin, client, server

I'm using Xamarin and https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl this plugin to connect my Iphone to Windows via TCP. I followed the examples on the github. I'am listening from a windows forms application and making my Iphone a client. I'm using usb cable and making my Iphone a hotspot. However, when I try to connect I'am getting an exception which is Connection Refused. I'am using localhost IP. Maybe that's the problem I don't know. I would be greatfull if anyone can help. All have a good day.

Comment: If your server is using localhost, then no external client will be able to connect to it.

Comment: What ip should I be using? Just one I make up? I am pretty new to this staff.

Comment: Use the IP already assigned to your server.